# Issue with background cover attribute (maybe skrollr related)

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I have a problem regarding my full image covering

Its supposed to be cover yet on my browser it doesn't actually cover the whole page for each "slide" in fact it seemingly has a black division between the two "slides" and also has too much width on my laptop...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bpiy2c2plez06rk/widthErrorSkrollr.zip

Here is the zip file, I would put the code here but there is a fair amount, I used dreamweavers built in fluid grid layout and have tried a few things, maybe its something simple, I dunno

Anyway, help would be appreciated!

Comment: try setting up a demo at jsfiddle, if you think the code is too much?

Comment: Please use plunkr or a similar service to share your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lukes/F5MKD/#&togetherjs=sPbLyv6AN3 here is the main stuff guys :)